# Django: Fetching value of field for an object in for loop

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Suppose I have a model named Visitor.

**models.py**

```
class Visitor(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Now what i need to is the following thing

**views.py**

```
myView(request):
    o = Visitor.objects.get(name='Ankit')
    FList = ['region','city','country'] #flist is the list of fields 
    for myField in FList:
        print(o.myField) 'I want to print value of each field for this particular object 'o'.'
```

I know print(o.myField) is completely incorrect because it will simply try to fetch value of 'myField' field for this particular object from Visitor model and 'myField' field doesn't exist in this model.

How can i achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pythons built in function [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
for myField in FList:
    print(getattr(o, myField))
```